Codable Expressions for Ratios of Zeroth-Order First Kind Bessel Functions
I need to evaluate the following expression:
$$\frac{J_0(ar)}{J_0(ar_0)}$$
Where $a$, $r$, and $r_0$ are constants. $a$ can be any complex number, $r_0$ is a positive non-zero real number, and $r$ ranges from 0 to $r_0$.
I am attempting to use python to evaluate the ratio and have used the scipy 'special' Bessel function, but as the arguments become large (specifically in the $\theta=45^\circ$ direction within the complex plane), the values of the individual functions become unbounded, producing 'nan' values, while the ratio should be well defined.
There are other instances where I have been able to take advantage of Continued Fraction Expressions for the ratio of different order Bessel functions of the same argument.
Is there a similarly codable expression for the ratio of Zeroth-Order First-Kind Bessel functions of different arguments?

What are some examples of arguments for calculations you're trying to do that fail? Also, the mpmath library for Python is good for doing calculations with arbitrary precision. It can return a finite value for $J_0(10^{20}(1+i))$, for example.

@DavidChew, the scipy.special function 'jv' gives infinite values for arguments with an imaginary part greater than 700 (for the zeroth order). e.g. jv(0,701j) = inf.
Though, your suggestion of the mpmath library is sufficient to close my problem.
There is only an hour left in the bounty, but if you post an answer I will accept it.

A product representation may simplify for the ratio of Bessel functions.

@DavidChew, Apparently I have 21 more hours to award the bounty. Again, if you write your comment into an answer, I will award you the bounty.  Thank you!

Thanks! I have posted an answer with the solution and some additional ideas.

(Extension of my comment)
The mpmath library for Python is good for doing calculations with arbitrary precision. It can return a finite value for $J_0(10^{20}(1+i))$, for example. This site could also provide additional resources for dealing with $J$.
Additionally, one of the more promising properties I found on Wikipedia (also found by TymaGaidash) was that $J_0(z)=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{j_{0,n}^2}\right)$ where $j_{0,n}$ is the $n$'th zero of $J_0$. Then it should be possible to use scipy to compute for large argument:
$\displaystyle\log\left(\frac{J_0(ar)}{J_0(ar_0)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(\frac{a^2r^2-j_{0,n}^2}{a^2r_0^2-j_{0,n}^2}\right)$
While it is easy to compute this sum for large $n$, say $n\approx10^7$, the precision for that $n$ is only a couple of decimal places, so there may be better methods for higher precision, such as asymptotic expansions. Either way, computing the $\log$ of the function first if possible should be finite with scipy even if $\frac{J_0(ar)}{J_0(ar_0)}$ itself is too large, and then exponentiating can still give finite results.

Thank you, David! I would upvote this, but I have gone bankrupt funding the bounty. I have accepted the answer.

Lol, I appreciate it, my first bounty!
